# Overloading the left shift operator for strings in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, bit, bit-shift

How can I overload the left shift operator for strings, can someone help me? :

```
const char*
{
    int operator<<(const char* rhs)
    {
        return std::atoi(this) + std::atoi(rhs);
    }
}

int main() {
    const char* term1 = "12";
    const char* term2 = "23";
    std::cout << (term1 << term2);
}
```

(above code does not compile)

Expected output: `35`

Comment: C doesn't have support for operator overloading. Don't spam tags

Comment: You will never be able to get that code to do what you want - operator overloads must involve at least one user-defined type.

Comment: Does this even compile? BTW - `atoi` is crap. Does to check for errors

Comment: @EdHeal No, this won't compile. The OP is asking how to re-write it so that it does compile. :)

Comment: Where in the post does it say that it does not compile?

Comment: `s/Expected/Desired/`

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry, i'll include that info, it does not compile. I think I have the answer anyway, this is not possible :(

Comment: @EdHeal It doesn't say that. It's kind of implied by the fact that the OP asked the question at all.

Comment: why not use std::string instead of char*? You cannot overload operator where both sides are primitive types. Just like you cannot change how to define int+int.

Comment: @achal - It *is* a shift operator, at least as far as the C++ spec is concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

juanchpanza's answer is right on the money. What you're trying to do can't be done because you're using a built-in type.

However, you can do it with custom types, including `std::string`.

The following program illustrates how to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

auto operator << (std::string a, std::string b) -> int
{
    return std::atoi(a.c_str()) + std::atoi(b.c_str());
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << (std::string("1") << std::string("2"));   
}
```

It's probably *not* a good idea to do it however.

Comment: better to use (const string& a, const string& b)

Comment: You can use `std::string_view` in C++17, and avoid much the overhead associated here with `std::string`. Can even make it more readable with the use of the user defined literal for string views.

Comment: @StoryTeller I can only agree. I'm not going to improve on the answer since I wouldn't recommend doing anything like this in the first place.

Comment: I can respect that :)

Comment: `atoi` can only be used safely if you already know that the string is parseable as an integer number, or if 0 represents an error anyway. Use `std::stoi` instead.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Again, I'm not going to improve on it. I would not recommend doing anything like this at all.

Answer (score 3):

C++ does not allow overloading operators purely for built-in types. So it is not possible to overload left shift for pointer to const char.